# How to display NFTs I own to my own website?

Tags: nft

I am trying to make a website where it gives a list of NFTs that I own. I’ve went as far as using MetaMask to login. As a reference, I am trying to do something like lazy.com where you can display the NFTs you own. Thank you.

Comment: Check opensea api https://docs.opensea.io/reference/api-overview.

Answer (score 0):

Alchemy has a dev doc for creating an NFT gallery - https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-create-an-nft-gallery